# Property 'errorReason' does not exist on type 'MessageWithMdEnforced'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, types

I have a project with meteor, react and typescript

Below is the part of code where I am getting the error

```
{message?.errorReason &&
   <div>{message?.errorReason}</div>
}
```

I am getting error

Property 'errorReason' does not exist on type 'MessageWithMdEnforced'

```
export type MessageWithMdEnforced = WithRequiredProperty<IMessage, 'md'>;
```

```
type WithRequiredProperty<Type, Key extends keyof Type> = Omit<Type, Key> & {
    [Property in Key]-?: Type[Property];
};
```

Why the error occurs ?
Can anyone tell me where to add `errorReason` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define type in `IMessage` interface.
You would  find it in your project

```
interface IMessage extends SomeClass{
   prop?: string,
   ...
   ...
   ...
   errorReason?: any
}
```